# javascript document.write css doesn't apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colors

HTML:

```
<div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
</div>
<button>Print</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("button").on("click", function(){
    var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"/css/product.css\" />");
            //printWindow.document.write("<style>#dvContainer{color: red;}</style>");

            printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
});
```

I need my div to change to red when the window appears, but nothing happened.

I tried using style code but my element is still black. I also tried the media print but nothing.

Any suggestions please? What am I doing incorrectly?
I'm testing this in the latest version of Chrome, and jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: "*I need my div to change to color red when the window apper*" by that you mean when the document loads?

Comment: `.html()` doesn't include the element itself.

Comment: if you are using jQuery you can just use `$("#dvContainer").css("color", "red");`... it's that simple...

Comment: I mean the window print-(in my page is red is taking the value from css). It didn't change the color. Yes I am using jquery and it didn't change even by this code you send me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!!!
Print media type of bootstrap code blocked me and was also the bug to block all the other css i had in my page. 
So I compliled a new bootstrap without the print media type and now is working!!!

Answer (score 1):

After our conversation what you want to do is to setup the print styles properly. Add this to products.css

```
@media print {
   body {
      background-color: red;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Still nothing I think is the same to enter this inside. Still black.

Comment: Have you enable styles in chrome print settings?

Comment: No i didnt ahhhh perhaps your right lets see... where are these settings?

Comment: Chrome - > print - > more options - > background graphics

Comment: Noooo it wasn't that. It was enable.

Comment: One question to which window you want to apply the bg color, the one with the button or the another that you create programmatically?

Comment: In the window print I need to apply my css.

Comment: @VasilisGreece This code should work, it is working for me. In the print window - make sure you enable "Background graphics" it is the last option, not sure how it is written in Greek but see my screenshot: http://puu.sh/np0Qz/121dd94382.png